# What kinds of errors does a func throw out in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, throws

I see some methods throw out errors in Apple's Documentation. But I can't find any information about what it throws.

Like this methods below. It's in FileManager class.

```
func moveItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) throws
```

I want to know what kinds of errors it throws. Where can I get related information?

Comment: don't you think that it is a question for google?

Comment: I tried. But I didn't get a answer. Maybe I haven't figured out the key words.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java, where the `throws` declaration requires a type, in Swift you will not know, what type of `Error` will be thrown. The only thing you know is that the object conforms to the `Error`-protocol.

If you know that a function throws a certein `Error` (because it's well documented), you will need to cast the caught object properly.

**Example:**

```
do {
    try moveItem(from: someUrl, to: otherUrl)
} catch {
    //there will automatically be a local variable called "error" in this block
    // let's assume, the function throws a MoveItemError (such information should be in the documentation)
    if error is MoveItemError {
        let moveError = error as! MoveItemError //since you've already checked that error is an MoveItemError, you can force-cast
    } else {
        //some other error. Without casting it, you can only use the properties and functions declared in the "Error"-protocol
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this information is useful to me. Is there any way to know what protocol it conforms? I want to know what happened when it failed.

Comment: Is that mean I should **get** information from `catch` block, not to **do** something in the `catch` block?

Comment: In your `catch`-block, there will be a local variable called `error`. This conforms to the protocol `Error`. If the documentation for a method indicates, that a certain object (let's assume it's called `CustomError`) is thrown, you have to cast `error` to that object with `as?` and/or check the type if `error` with `if error is CustomError { //handle the CustomError }`

Comment: I know how to throw `CustomError` in my code. But I still have doubts about about Apple's Documentation. Do all the classes from Apple's frameworks  conform to the protocol `Error`? If not, can you show me one than indicate a certain object(like `CustomError`)? I haven't found any one. :(

Comment: In Swift, any error a functions throws, needs to conform to the `Error`-protocol. [The Swift Programming Language - Representing and Throwing Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID509) If the documentation of a function indicates that a certain object like `CustomError` (which will conform to `Error`) is thrown, you can check the type of the object like in the example I've added to my answer